# How to add custom CSS to my c# code? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, development, css

I have created a visual webpart and I need to add custom css on it. Example I want to add the following css:

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-node {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 139px !important;
font-family: arial,helvetica;
font-size: 12px !important;
cursor: default;
border: 0px solid #b5d9ea;
border-radius: 0px !important;
color: white;
background-color: #25a0da;
}
```

to my c# project. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: I think it would be better to add the CSS to the site/page where the webpart will be used, easier to change it when you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the CSS to your **Google Organization Chart** webpart than you can just apply it from the ASPX page like (Usual way) below.

```
<style type="text\css">
.google-visualization-orgchart-node {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 139px !important;
font-family: arial,helvetica;
font-size: 12px !important;
cursor: default;
border: 0px solid #b5d9ea;
border-radius: 0px !important;
color: white;
background-color: #25a0da;
}
</style>
```

Check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/w8Ytq/2/

Comment: Check the proper Class Name OR IDs using the IE's **Developer Tools**. than apply same classes to your css.

Answer (score 1):

When you are working in visual webpart, you can add css & javascript in following ways.

**Option 1:**

- Open your ascx file in the webpart.
- Add `<style type="text/css"> </style>` tag
- Add your css properties into this style tag.
- Use the classes in you html block.

**Option 2:**

- Create a text file. paste entire css code in it.
- Do not add `<style>` tag in it.
- Save it with .css extension.
- Upload it to any library like Site Assets
- Open your ascx file in the webpart.
- Add reference to your .css file
- Use the classes in you html block.

similar for js code as well.
 - Use  tag
 - or save it in .js file and use its reference.

Comment: welcome. You can up vote and mark it as answer, It will help someone looking for same